# Which is the base url of sourcemappingurl: relative from html or js?

Tags: javascript, source-maps

Suppose that there is a js file with source-map in subdirectory of a html file.

- index.html (uses js/myjs.js)
- js/myjs.js
- js/myjs.js.map

then which is the sourceMappingURL comment of myjs.js ?

```
//# sourceMappingURL=myjs.js.map
```

or

```
//# sourceMappingURL=js/myjs.js.map
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I lookup to the [specification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/).

When the source mapping URL is not absolute, then it is relative to the generated code’s “source origin”. The source origin is determined by one of the following cases:

- If the generated source is not associated with a script element that
  has a “src” attribute and there exists a //# sourceURL comment in the
  generated code, that comment should be used to determine the source
  origin. Note: Previously, this was “//@ sourceURL”, as with “//@
  sourceMappingURL”, it is reasonable to accept both but //# is
  preferred.
- If the generated code is associated with a script element
  and the script element has a “src” attribute, the “src” attribute of
  the script element will be the source origin.
- If the generated code
  is associated with a script element and the script element does not
  have a “src” attribute, then the source origin will be the page’s
  origin.
- If the generated code is being evaluated as a string with the
  eval() function or via new Function(), then the source origin will be
  the page’s origin.

So if you use `<script src="js/myjs.js">` in index.html the `js/myjs.js.map` is used.