# Why does Chrome display sourceMappingURL relative paths this way?

Tags: source-maps

Given a sourceMappingURL comment with a relative path like `//# sourceMappingURL=dep.js.map`, I understand that to mean the path is  [relative to the current file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40907492/5447019). But when I create a project with minified source files and their sourcemaps in the same directory, Chrome displays them like this:

[image: chrome dev tools shows sourcemap under duplicated subdirectories]

Even though the dep.js sourcemap is under extra subdirectories, Chrome still shows me the contents of the sourcemap. When I right-click dep.js and open in new tab, the URL in the new tab is invalid--it contains the aforementioned extra subdirectories (/scripts/dep/scripts/dep/dep.js instead of /scripts/dep/dep.js).

What *should* the sourceMappingURL be?

Comment: I get exactly the same behavior as described above in Firefox, and / or using an absolute path instead of a relative one.